# Websocket não faz a conexão com servidor

Tags: html5, websocket

Não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão com servidor.

Obs:  o navegador dá suporte a *websocket*. 

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma

```
var socket = new WebSocket('sw: localhost:8080');
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro? se possível poste mais detalhes.

Comment: Sim. O Firefox diz que não foi possível estabelecer a conexão e o IE reporta WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 200, OK. Estou usando o WAMP e Apache tá rodando na porta 8080. Vc acha que a conexão deve ser direcionada para um server php?

Comment: como que você montou seu servidor de sockets ?

Comment: você deveria dar uma olhada [neste plugin](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2):

Em uma breve resposta, você provavelmente esqueceu do `//` e você trocou o `ws` por `sw`, acredito que o correto deveria ser:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique a porta que está configurada no servidor para o WebSocket, a porta 8080 normalmente é utilizada para HTTP e o WebSocket utiliza outra porta. Encontre a porta correta e mude no construtor do WebScoket no javascript.